# Open vector editor for Mono on Linux

Tags: linux, image-editor, vector-graphics, mono

The tool should allow to draw vector graphics.
It should be something similar to [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/), but for vector graphics instead of raster graphics.

I found 3 articles:

- 2009, Andrea Contoli, Simple Vector Shapes,
  CPOL, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19195/Simple-Vector-Shapes
- 2004, big71, SVGPad - Application and class library for editing SVG documents
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8207/SVGPad-Application-and-class-library-for-editing-S
- 2002, Joseph M. Newcomer, A Simple Vector Editor
  Proprietary, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2392/A-Simple-Vector-Editor

I want a base to implement my own tool. That is why technology choice is important to me.

Linked questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298380/net-winform-diagram-library
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838579/a-good-2d-primitive-rendering-library-for-c-net
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486014/open-source-net-vector-graphics-editor
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926551/choosing-a-diagramming-library-for-net
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525421/drawing-svg-in-net-c
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979518/how-do-i-build-a-diagramming-application-in-net

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations, please take a look at our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and our [answer quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality)

Comment: What's this wall of links?

Comment: that's fault of site engine, which doesn't recognise this type of links

Answer (score -2):

- BSD, https://github.com/piccolo2d/piccolo2d.net
- Apache, https://github.com/dalssoft/diagramnet
- GPLv2, http://easydiagram.codeplex.com/
- GPLv2 + Proprietary, http://opendiagram.codeplex.com/
- GPLv2 + Proprietary, http://nshape.codeplex.com/
- CPOL, http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/711081/DrawTools
- MsPL, https://github.com/vvvv/SVG

Comment: This answer does not mention how the programs fulfill the requirements